# Error Invalid gaurdfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm very new to rails and attempting to execute a guardfile in a tutorial but it's throwing and error and I'm not entirely sure why but I'm sure its pretty simple. Thanks in advance!

Updated error message
18:27:31 - ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is:

> [#] 
>   [#] undefined method `merge' for nil:NilClass, 
>   [#] backtrace: 
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/dsl.rb:183:in`block in guard'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/dsl.rb:182:in `each'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/dsl.rb:182:in`guard'
>   [#]   (dsl)> ./Guardfile:18:in `evaluate'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/dsl.rb:377:in`instance_eval'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/dsl.rb:377:in `evaluate'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:91:in`evaluate'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard.rb:134:in `_evaluate'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard.rb:49:in`setup'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/commander.rb:32:in `start'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/cli/environments/valid.rb:16:in`start_guard'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/cli.rb:122:in `start'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in`run'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in`dispatch'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/aruba_adapter.rb:32:in`execute'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/lib/guard/aruba_adapter.rb:19:in `execute!'
>   [#]   (dsl)> $GEM_PATH[0]/gems/guard-2.13.0/bin/_guard-core:11:in`'

Relevant code

```
    guard :minitest do
  # with Minitest::Unit
  guard :minitest, spring: true, all_on_start: false do
  watch(%r{^test/(.*)\/?test_(.*)\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.*/)?([^/]+)\.rb$})     { |m| "test/#{m[1]}test_#{m[2]}.rb" }
  watch(%r{^test/test_helper\.rb$})      { 'test' }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We'll need more information, specifically the relevant source code, before we'll be able to help you.

Comment: If you're able to link to the tutorial and cite the line number you're at that might help too.

Comment: Please add the Guardfile code. If there's a line number for the error, that would be helpful.

Comment: you have a guard inside a guard? remove the first line of code there.

Comment: That worked! Thanks alot.